# Binding property of usercontrol with class' member

Tags: c#, universal

Making a Windows 8: Universal Application, I have the following question:

Why the `Height` of each control in `MyGridView.Items` does not change after the new value is assigned to `height` in `MyGridView_SelectionChanged` method? Within the `OnNavigatedTo` method it sets the `Height` value correctly...

```
public sealed partial class NewPage : Page
{
    public double height;


    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        foreach (var card in e.Parameter as List<MyClass>)
        {
            MyControl myControl = new MyControl(card);
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(myControl, HeightProperty, new Binding { UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, Source = this, Path = new PropertyPath("height") });
            MyGridView.Items.Add(myControl);
        }
    }

    private void MyGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        height = 100;
    }
}
```

I also tried with the `DependencyProperty`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyGridViewItemHeightProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyGridViewItemHeight", typeof(double), typeof(GridViewItem), null);

public double MyGridViewItemHeight
{
    set { SetValue(MyGridViewItemHeightProperty, value); }
    get { return (double)GetValue(MyGridViewItemHeightProperty); }
}
```

and

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    foreach (var card in e.Parameter as List<MyClass>)
    {
        MyControl myControl = new MyControl(card);
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(myControl, HeightProperty, new Binding { UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, Source = this, Path = new PropertyPath("MyGridViewItemHeightProperty") });

    }
}
```

but it gave the same result...